# EmberJS: models associations not setup when batch "loading" from the store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Somewhere in my app, the server returns a bunch of records at once. The way I handle this in Ember is something like this:

```
$.each(json["foos"], function(idx, val){
    DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Foo, val)
});
```

and it works fine, except when it comes to associations. If I have the following:

```
App.Dad = DS.Model.extend({
    sons: DS.hasMany('App.Son')
})

App.Son = DS.Model.extend({
    dad: DS.belongsTo('App.Dad')
})
```

and if in the code I do:

```
$.each(json["dads"], function(idx, val){
    DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Dad, val)
});

$.each(json["sons"], function(idx, val){
    DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Son, val)
});
```

then each Son "knows" about its Dad (I can do `a_son.get('dad')`), but Dads don't know about their sons: `a_dad.get('sons').get('length')` returns 0.

I guess the reason is when I load a Dad, his Sons are not loaded yet. But is there a way to make this work?

I can do it "manually" like this:

```
$.each(json["sons"], function(idx, val){
    DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Son, val);
    App.Dad.find(val.dad_id).get('sons').pushObject(App.Son.find(val.id));
});
```

but it seems weird to have to do this.

I put together a JSFiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/eq8pB/1/

Thanks!

PJ

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a **'one-to-many'** relationship you have to reopen `App.Dad` class.

```js
App.Dad = DS.Model.extend({
    someProperties: (...)
});

App.Son = DS.Model.extend({
    dad: DS.belongsTo('App.Dad')
});

App.Dad.reopen({
    sons: DS.hasMany('App.Son')
});
```

You should take a look to [`ember-data test`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/relationships/one_to_many_relationships_test.js) this is a good way to understand how relationships works in ember.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Unfortunately it does not work. Just to be clear: the relationship works fine as far as I can tell. It is just that I need to "manually" tell a Dad who are his Sons when I load from Json. Cf my edit above.

Comment: Thomas, I can actually confirm that there is no need to reopen the class. Maybe it was necessary in the past? Not anymore though (thanks to the fact - I guess - that we pass the associations names as a string instead of an object?).

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else: for store.load to build the association, you do need to pass in JSON the corresponding data for BOTH parent and child. I mean:

```
DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Dad, {id: 1, name: "Dad"});
DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Son, {id: 1, name: "Son", dad_id: 1});

// Dad of ID 1 will NOT know who his sons are. cf http://jsfiddle.net/eq8pB/1/
// Son of ID 1 will know who his dad is.

DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Dad, {id: 1, name: "Dad", sons: [1]});
DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.Son, {id: 1, name: "Son", dad_id: 1});

// Dad of ID 1 WILL know who his sons are. cf http://jsfiddle.net/eq8pB/3/
// Son of ID 1 will know who his dad is.
```